# Typescript: Passing a callback instead of a function reference causes the result to be of a type unknown

Tags: typescript, callback

In the example bellow the type of `a` is a `string` (that's OK), but the type of `b` is `unknown`. And there is an TS error on the line `x => doSomething(x)`:

> Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.(2345)

(If the following code doesn't look very useful, it's because it's an extremely simplified version of a real code that has the same problem.)

```
type F<a> = (x: a) => a

function returnF<a>(f: F<a>): F<a> {
    return f
}

function doSomething(s: string): string {
    return s
}

const a = returnF(  // 'a' is a string
    doSomething
)("A")

const b = returnF(  // 'b' is unknown
    x => doSomething(x)
)("B")

const c = returnF<string>(  // 'c' is a string
    x => doSomething(x)
)("C")
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYgHgIYD4YF4YAoAeAuGJASgzSWGADMBXAOwGMQBLAe1pgCcoRqPbFUWSgQEoiI5GgDewGHM7de7SsAC+FGg2ZsYAExYBlFgFtuACya0A5lgDOBWyA6Wr4mI+fWYM+Qp593NQp6NkdCDD8lOCxZeX0jUxALa2AiLAAiAEF0omDQkBgAIwiuf34Y3xxSPUMTcxdcXLT0gCEcvNow+hLFPkQPFxQK+Sr0NHi6pIacJoyAYXagA)

My questions are:

1. Why changing `returnF(doSomething)` to `returnF(x => doSomething(x))` introduces the error?
2. Is there a way to change the code so that I can still use `returnF(x => doSomething(x))`, but I don't have to specify the type `<a>` on every place, where `returnF` is used?

Answer (score 0):

Because `x => doSomething(x)` is an anonymous function and there is no type specified for parameter `x`. `unknown` is the default value for the unspecified parameter. If you want it to work properly you should specify the type explicitly like `(x:string) => doSomething(x)`

[Play](https://tsplay.dev/N752DW)